# This code works on one machine and fails on another. How to debug?

Tags: ruby, byebug

I have a function that looks like this:

```
def search_street_addresses(query, limit: 100)
  if query.is_a? String
    query = @address_parser.parse(query)

    fail ArgumentError, "Invalid address string" if query.nil?
  end

  # ...
```

And it's called like this:

```
begin
  results = @ndi.search_street_addresses(query)
rescue ArgumentError
  raise CommandError, "Failed to parse address"
end
```

It works perfectly on my machine. I have stepped through the code with a debugger, and everything works as expected. The problem is that on the machine of a co-worker (with the exact same code as I and the exact same Ruby version) a seemingly impossible thing happens. Between the call `@ndi.search_street_addresses(query)` and the first line of the function, an `ArgumentError` is raised. I have inserted a breakpoint like this:

```
begin
  require "byebug"; byebug
  results = @ndi.search_street_addresses(query)
# ...
```

And attempted to step into the function, but the `ArgumentError` is raised after the first `step` I take, without me ever entering the function. I have also set a breakpoint in the function:

```
def search_street_addresses(query, limit: 100)
  require "byebug"; byebug
  if query.is_a? String
    # ...
```

But the `ArgumentError` is raised without the breakpoint triggering. This only happens on his machine, everything works perfectly on mine. I don't have the slightest clue how to debug this since the `ArgumentError` is seemingly raised somewhere in the Ruby ether outside the reach of Byebug.

So; how do I debug this?

Comment: check his installed gems and topmost/global requires, there's some possibility that `search_street_addresses` was automatically rewritten and wrapped by some tool, and the code injected by the tool crashes (I don't know why, maybe it doesnt support hash-params?). Just guessing. However, the first thing you should do is to try to catch the **stacktrace** at the moment his machine throws ArgumentError. What does it point to? `search_street_addresses`?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: The `ArgumentError` was thrown immediately on the line `results = @ndi.search_street_addresses(query)`. I couldn't even step into the function.

Comment: Ok, but did you see the actual stacktrace that Ruby produces? Debugger/stepper is also human-written code, and I have seen many times (in different languages/platforms) cases, where the debugger silently skipped over a few autogenerated things when "stepping into". However, upon crashes, they are visible on stacks.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Sadly no, because the ArgumentError was caught by my code to produce a simple error message. I should have added a breakpoint where the exception was caught and checked the stacktrace. I didn't think of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anticlimactic answer; my co-worker reinstalled Ruby and now everything works. I'm not sure whether to delete this question or leave this answer to perhaps save a couple of hours of pointless debugging for somebody else.

Comment: Hm.. this **exactly** supports the 'gems' and 'automatic method rewriter' option. When Ruby was reinstalled, all gems were thrown out and he probably downloaded only the currently needed ones. So all extra modules, all C/C++ plugins, etc, were discarded. I think you could try to detect which gem (if any, really) was the culprit, install-uninstall one by one and recheck, but probably he will not remember what gems he had before :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: He has the exact same set of gems now as be did before the reinstall. I know this because his Ruby installation exists only to run my project and the only installed gems were the requirements of my project. That doesn't disprove your theory though.

Comment: puff.. true, but if he doesn't play with Ruby on daily basis and other projects, that's so much less probable..

Comment: I'm still trying to come up with any other cause than 'method rewriter'.. Gems aside, ORM layer could inject some transparent proxy or wrapper, but then, it should crash on your machine too. I think that bugs in Ruby engine can be crossed out, as it usually does not end in ArgumentError but plain huge crash of the VM, C-level trace included but who knows. Anyways, that's great you were able to solve it. Just a bit of pity that he just reinstalled and did not make any hard backup to allow other to trace the bug.. The findings could be very interesting! Still, I hope it won't be back :))